# How to assemble function name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

this is an example function:

```
function processFanGrowth() {
    console.log('fanGrowth');
}
```

and an object "data" which has a property name "FanGrowth"

```
for(var property in data) {
      // here i'm trying to generate the function name.
      funcName = "process" + property;
      funcName();
}
```

i'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Comment: when you apply "process" you are converting whatever property might be to a string

Comment: @Pogrindis: `property` is already a string. That's the point.

Comment: Refer this [previously answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can invoke the function as a property of the object whose scope it is defined in, e.g. for a function defined in global scope:

```
window['process' + property]();
```

Comment: ty this worked perfectly, can accept the answer only after 9 mins.

is this method of function calling not recommended or bad practice by any means?

Comment: @tareq: It's not too bad, though you have to be careful that `property` never comes from user input. I'd prefer storing references to functions (as opposed to function names) where possible.

Comment: yes in my case "property" never comes from the user input, as for storing references to functions; is there any helpful sources to help me understand this a bit more?

ty again.

Comment: @tareq: Well, which book are you using? It should teach you that sort of thing.

Comment: actually i'm not using any books, i'm learning by doing coding and reading reddit and some articles whenever i can.

Comment: @tareq: Get a good, peer-reviewed book.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax should work:

```
window["functionName"](arguments);
```

In your case:

```
for(var property in data) {
      // here i'm trying to generate the function name.
      funcName = "process" + property;
      window["functionName"]();
}
```